# Hide Kendo UI Combobox options based on certain values

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, dojo, telerik, kendo-combobox

I have a kendo UI combobox that has values: User 1, User 2, User 3 and User 4 and I would to hide User 1 and User 2 and only show User 3 and User 4 based on a certain condition. Here is the [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eyORO/5) for that. Kindly let me know how I can achieve the above.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
var _flt = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
// Show only User 3 and User 4
var users = $("#users").data("kendoComboBox");

_flt.filters.push({ field: 'value', operator: "contains", value: "2" });
_flt.filters.push({ field: 'value', operator: "contains", value: "3" });

$('#users').kendoComboBox().data('kendoComboBox').dataSource.filter(_flt);
```

Comment: And what if I would like to hide all the options? Could you please update the answer for that?

Comment: You could use `$('#users').kendoComboBox().data('kendoComboBox').setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource());` to empty your combobox. More information here: [Click](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-empty-combobox-)

Comment: Thanks again!. Very helpful.