# Kendo Combobox losing html fields on filtering

Tags: javascript, html, filter, combobox, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Combobox and I have asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582983/hide-kendo-ui-combobox-options-based-on-certain-values) earlier. The filtering works fine but after the filtering is done, the options in the select list lose their attributes. Any reason why? Kindly let me know.

Here is the [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eyORO/12) for that.

**Before Filtering:**

```
<select id="users">
                <option value="1" code="user1" data-message="OK1">User 1</option>
                <option value="2" code="user2" data-message="OK2">User 2</option>
              <option value="3" code="user3" data-message="OK3">User 3</option>
              <option value="4" code="user4" data-message="OK4">User 4</option>

                  </select>
```

**After Filtering:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
< select id="users" data - role="combobox" aria - disabled="false" aria - readonly="false" style="display: none;">
  <option value="2">User 2</option>// lost code and data-message
      <option value="3">User 3</option> // lost code and data-message
          </select>
```

Cheers.

**Update:**
The issue is that the control is already initialized server-side and I am just performing the filtering on the client side. Is there no way to perform the filtering without re-initializing the control all over again?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably take a slightly different approach and do it this way.

- Create a template for the combobox items
- load the data from somewhere (in the example I have just created an array in JS.
- create the Kendo Combobox and assign the datasource and template.
- perform the filtering against the data

[Example Dojo here](http://dojo.telerik.com/eyORO/13)

```
<!-- Template for Combobox Items -->  
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

  <span value="#: value #" code="#: code #" data-message="#: message#">#: displayText #</span>
</script>

  <!-- Element to convert to Kendo Combobox -->

  <div id='users'></div>


          <script>
            // Data for the ComboBox
            var data = [{value: "1", code: "user1", message:"OK1", displayText: "User 1"},
                       {value: "2", code: "user2", message:"OK2", displayText: "User 2"},
                        {value: "3", code: "user3", message:"OK3", displayText: "User 3"},
                        {value: "4", code: "user4", message:"OK4", displayText: "User 4"}
                       ]



              $(document).ready(function() {

                // Create the ComboBox 
                $('#users').kendoComboBox({

                  dataSource: data,
                  dataTextField: "displayText",
                  dataValueField: "value",
                  template: kendo.template($("#template").html())

                });

                //filtering
               var _flt = { logic: "or", filters: [] };

                _flt.filters.push({ field: 'value', operator: "contains", value: "2" });
                _flt.filters.push({ field: 'value', operator: "contains", value: "3" });

                $('#users').getKendoComboBox().dataSource.filter(_flt);
                //select the first item
                $('#users').getKendoComboBox().select(0);



              });

          </script>
```

Comment: hello @codingbadger, thanks for your answer. The issue is that the control is already initialized server-side and I am just performing the filtering on the client side. Is there no way to perform the filtering without re-initializing the control all over again?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by initialised server side? Are you using the MVC wrappers ?

Comment: As in they have been done on the server-side (I dont have control over it) and all I can do is manipulate it client side. Do you reckon you could help me with a client side solution for this please?

Comment: By server-side I mean, just do `$('#users').kendoComboBox().data("kendoComboBox");` for initialization and then imagine that the select list is converted into a comboBox. Now once we have this, run through my code in the Dojo and try to achieve the same without losing HTML attributes.

Comment: This is not possible. When you convert the already defined `select` element to a kendo ComboBox it does not copy all attributes across to the new Kendo element. You would have to do this manually.